# What is equant Class to "NSScanner" Class in Android?

Tags: java, android, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, nsscanner

I am working on one bel project on android and converting the one application already developed in iOS I am stuck one bunch of lines and didn't find equant code in java

I need to convert the below code and want a class performing below actions in android.

```
NSString *strOneHour = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08x",CFSwapInt32HostToLittle(timeProcessdata[0])];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:strOneHour];
int oneHour;
[scanner setScanLocation:0]; // bypass '#' character
[scanner scanHexInt:&oneHour];
```

Thanks

Comment: What your code does is simply converting `timeProcessdata[0]` from big endian to little endian. The `NSScanner` is for converting the `uint32_t` to an `int`. Since these are not distinct types in Java, you don't need scanners for this in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Here is android's [scanner](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Scanner.html)

Hope this is what you are looking for.